# titletoc fails with custom titlecontents

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

I'm using `titletoc` for having a partial index going down to paragraphs.

I wrote a custom formatting for it using `\titlecontents` and `\titlecontents*`.

In some cases (some specific combination of subsections, paragraphs, and text), it fails with the error:

```
./MWE.ptc
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \ttll@lsubsection 
l.6 \contentsline {paragraph}{Bla}{1}
```

A minimum non-working example is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{lsubsection}[0pt]{}{}{}{}
\titlecontents*{lparagraph}[0pt]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[char]
\printcontents[char]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\paragraph{Blo}

\subsection{Ciao}

\paragraph{Bla}
As seen in 

\stopcontents[char]

\end{document}
```

and the file `.ptc` which seems to be involved in the error has the following content:

```
\babel@toc {english}{}
\ttl@starttoc {char@1}
\contentsline {paragraph}{Blo}{1}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {0.1}Ciao}{1}% 
\contentsline {paragraph}{Bla}{1}% 
\ttl@stoptoc {char@1}
\contentsfinish
```

Where does this error come from?
Thanks!

Comment: do you really have `\paragraph` before `\subsection` it seems that `titletoc` don't expect this.

Comment: I agree, that seems to be the problem. The sectioning of the MWE is weird as it is the minimal example I could find. If you add a "section" at the begin of the MWE, it still fails. If you add a "subsection" it works.

Comment: The version in GitHub should work ( https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec ). I was working on it, and I'll upload it to CTAN in 1 or 2 weeks.